# Optional 'IS NULL' WHERE clause based on a parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query with a `WHERE` clause

```
WHERE [column1] = 'some value'
AND [column2] IS NULL
```

I want to make the `IS NULL` portion optional based on a parameter.

If value for `param1` for example, is supplied, this part of the `WHERE` clause should be ignored.

```
AND [column2] IS NULL
```

EDIT:

I am not open to use dynamic SQL as it would beat the purpose of why I'm doing this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this help: `WHERE [column2] IS NULL AND (@yourParam IS NULL OR @yourParam = [column1])`

Comment: Thanks @Rumpelstinsk but the parameter won't be used for comparison to `[column2]`. Just need the parameter to check whether to include the `[column2] IS NULL` `WHERE` clause or not

Comment: added an answer with conditional or.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE [column1] = 'some value'
AND (@param1 IS NOT NULL OR [column2] IS NULL)
```

If @param1 is set, the second condition will always evaluate to true, if not, it will check if [column2] is null

Comment: As  @Damien_The_Unbeliever have mentioned this simplifies the work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this..Also, you can use `IsNull()` as well.

```
WHERE ((@param1 IS NULL OR @param1 = '') and [column1] = 'some value' and [column2] IS NULL)
OR (@param1 IS not NULL and [column1] = 'some value');
```

Answer (score 0):

**This should work:**

```
WHERE (ISNULL('some value', '') = '' OR column1 = 'some value') 
AND (ISNULL('some value', '') = '' OR column2 = 'some value')
```